# Using a single actor for in and out ports of a Flow

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I'm starting to explore the akka-stream API and I'm looking to test it out. I have a specific use case I can't seem to find an appropriate streaming API to use.

The idea is similar to the following with a bit of a twist:

Source(1 to 10).mapAsync(num => actorRef ? Request(num)).to(Sink.foreach(println))

In this case the ask will return a single message through the future. I'd like to return more than one message for each request sent to the actor. For example:

1. ActorRef gets sent Request(2)
2. ActorRef sends N messages out of the flow.
3. ActorRef gets sent Request(3)
4. ActorRef sends M messages out of the flow.

I can add extra logic into the Actor to aggregate/buffer these extra messages into a Iterable of some sort but I'm wondering if I'm missing something in the API to handle a case like this.

The closest I've come while looking through the docs is using a Sink.actorRefWithAck and Source.queue with Flow.fromSinkAndSourceMat and passing the materialized SourceQueue to the actorRef before acking the onInitMessage. This allows control of up and downstream back pressure while handling one-to-many messages through the flow. It seems counter productive in making the Graph easy to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking for `flatMapConcat`.

```
Source(1 to 10).flatMapConcat(num => 
  // Dummy example - outputs first 5 successors for each incoming element
  Source(num to (num + 5))
).to(Sink.foreach(println))
```

This way you let Akka lift all the reactive streams weight, and you let no bare actor pollute your pipeline.

Documentation [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.16/scala/stream/stages-overview.html#flatMapConcat).

Comment: Thanks. That does seem to solve the example I outlined much better. However, if the actorRef is required due to integrating with some existing actor system (i.e. An external actor/function that when requested sends back a series of messages) I seem to get back to the issue I had originally where I can't seem to connect them together before materialization.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately what you are looking for doesn't seem to exist.  The [ask pattern](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/futures.html#Use_With_Actors), e.g. the `?` method, can only return 1 value.  Therefore, when you do something like

```
type Input = ???
type Outupt = ???

def askActorFlow(actorRef : ActorRef) : Flow[Input, Output, NotUsed] = 
  Flow[Input] mapAsync { input => (actorRef ? input).mapTo[Output] }
```

You can only get 1 value at a time back from the ActorRef.

The work around you suggested, e.g. "add extra logic into the Actor to aggregate/buffer these extra messages into a Iterable", is a better solution anyway.  It makes it easier for your Actor users to know they will get only 1 response back for any query.  Otherwise, the user will never truly know if they've gotten the "complete" answer back from the Actor after a query or if more data is forthcoming.